# C# Linq to aggregate results and compute averages

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, sqlite

I have created a sqlite db. Now I need a table where I can store the quantity bought by my clients and the average price they paid. 
The code is in C# and the table has the following structure:

ClientID; ItemID; Quantity; Price; Date;

where I store my client ID and the price they paid when they bought a given quantity of an item on a given date.

It happens that the same client can buy the same item on multiple days and pay a different price. 
What I need is to aggregate all the quantity each client bought for a given item and what is the average price he paid. 
I assume this can be done in Linq to make it efficient but I am not sure how to set up the query for the need above. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
purchases.GroupBy(g => new { g.ClientId, g.ItemId })
         .Select(g => new
                      {
                           ClientId = g.Key.ClientId,
                           ItemId = g.Key.ItemId,
                           Price = g.Sum(p => p.Price * p.Quantity) / g.Sum(p => p.Quantity)
                        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try anything? How about:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => new {x.ClientID, x.ItemID})
            .Select(
                g =>
                    new
                    {
                        g.Key.ClientID,
                        g.Key.ItemID,
                        AvgPrice = g.Average(c => c.Price), 
                        SumQuantity = g.Sum(c => c.Quantity)
                    });
```